# Naming siblings with same sounding chinese characters

Tags: characters, names

I would like to name my baby daughter "嫣" which is written as "yān", per pinyin.

However my elder daughter's name is "彥" which is pronounced as "yàn".

Is it considered taboo to give my daughters the similarly pronounced name, though it is different in Chinese?

Comment: Closing as "Primarily opinion-based".

Answer (score 2):

I never heard of such kind of "taboo". But if you are very sensitive with this for some reasons like you believe in things like `周易取名`, you may search `周易取名` on Google or Baidu. I think most of the key/original information is in Chinese.

Anyway, I think `嫣` is a very good name for a girl while `彥` sounds like a boy's name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such "taboo".

And I think it's very beautiful name, when you have one more child, you can also pick the name in "yan" series. e.g. 燕

But never pick the names in the same tone for different children. Same tone means 燕 and 艳 are in the same tone: yan4

Comment: What if you have more than children than there are tones?

Answer (score 0):

No such Taboo.

`嫣` is a very nice character used in name. `嫣` in most time means beautiful smile and also means someone is very beautiful. I have a lot of girl classmates using `嫣` in their names.

`彦` means people with knowledge and good morality. I once have a boy classmate having `彦` in his name.